# Как с помощью InputInterface в Symfony присвоить значение переменной?

Tags: symfony4

Как с помощью InputInterface в Symfony присвоить значение переменной, а именно, чтоб в консоли выводилось сообщение "Введите имя:", после ввода имени значение присваивалось $name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать Question Helper.